# is it possible to have multiple image styles for one uploaded image in drupal 8

Tags: caching, media

I have my main story pages. I have one image style set on the content type display page for 880 x 495. I also want to have a image style set for thumbnails sizes of these photos. But as I see it I can only have one or the other. Is there a way to apply multiple image styles to the same uploaded photo field in drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse images using different image sizes - as far as I am aware there isn't a way to do this using the Drupal Field UI - but you could (for example) override the node display using views for more customisation including the ability to use the same image field using multiple image styles.

Comment: Not the best solution but it works well enough. I needed thumbnails and big sizes for a separate website and am using Drupal as a decoupled CMS. So far having a view with a new image style works. Thanks.